# fastlane finished with errors Unauthorized Access

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, fastlane

While sending my application to the testflight via fastlane, I faced with this error:

> Unauthorized Access

```
**FastLanelane summary**

| 1    | opt_out_usage      | 0           |

| 2    | default_platform   | 0           |

| 3    | update_fastlane    | 0           |

| 4    | clear_derived_data | 0           |

| 5    | cocoapods          | 3           |

| 6    | gym                | 87          |

|    | pilot              | 3           |
```

> ERROR [2019-03-01 15:51:34.03]: **fastlane finished with errors**
>
> Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane... Search
>   query: The request could not be completed because:    Unauthorized
>   Access

Here is my Fasfile:

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do

    update_fastlane
    clear_derived_data
    cocoapods(clean: true, use_bundle_exec: false)

    # Build
    gym(clean: true, suppress_xcode_output: true, workspace: "com.xxxx.xcworkspace", scheme: "com.xxxx")

    # Submit to iTunes Connect (upload_to_testflight)
    pilot(skip_submission: true, skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true)

    upload_symbols_to_crashlytics # Upload dSYM symbolication files to Crashlytics
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Case

be sure that your role permission should be at least the **[App Manager](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)!**

### In My Case

I noticed that I entered the two-factor [Authentication (6-digit code) code](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification) incorrectly.

Remember that, starting on **February 27, 2019** Apple requiring all developers to have [two-factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915) enabled for their Apple IDs, with two-factor necessary for signing into Developer accounts after that date. Means it's necessary for our fastlane flows too.

Comment: FYI, 2FA is only required for developer accounts with the Account Holder role. Normal process is to create a separate CI account with lower permissions

Comment: Thank you for update @AaronBrager, I'll check that soon as possible. Best